# No user messages on Chatbase transcripts

Tags: chatbase

I've been trying to take advantage of the Transcripts feature in Chatbase, but whenever I open a transcript all the user messages are shown as `(No content)`.

The messages sent by the bot are all shown properly and the order of the messages is correct as well (both user and bot). On the messages report tab I can see the user messages so they are being sent across properly.

I'm sending all the messages using the [generic message API](https://chatbase.com/documentation/generic), with the original text on the `message` field.

This has been happening consistently for me on all projects, so I'm probably doing something wrong..any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work on Chatbase and would be happy to look into your issue.  If you could please contact chatbase-support@google.com and provide the api key, the name of the bot, or the email address you used to create the account I will be happy to look into the issue for you.

Comment: I've sent an email with additional information for debugging.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information, Rick. We were able to determine that the issue was caused by our update endpoint. Due to the fact that there is no content field, the original content of the updated messages was being overwritten with the empty string.  The fix for this bug is now live and we have confirmed that the original content is persisting for updates sent since the fix was implemented.  We are working to restore your historical message content as well.